# Vue Material Design Textfield Underline Not Showing

Tags: vuejs2, material-design

I am using the Material Design framework for Vue but when I add a textfield to the page the animation works but the underline doesn't show.

I added the following to my main.js file:

```
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
import {MdField, MdButton} from 'vue-material/dist/components'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is inside

import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing some classes somewhere? Looking on their docs for input and at the example they give, the underline is set using the pseudo ::after and ::before elements:

```
# ::before
.md-field.md-theme-demo-light:before {
  background-color: #448aff;
  background-color: var(--md-theme-demo-light-primary,#448aff)
}

# ::after
.md-field.md-theme-demo-light:after {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.42);
}
```

Which looks to be setting the colours with the 'md-theme-demo-light' class.

Comment: That should be included in the material design css with `import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'`